# JIRA Import CSV and link new issue to existing issues

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

Currently I have a CSV with two columns:

1. is test of
2. is tested by

When I import the issues I map them by Links and Sub-Tasks/Issue Id.
However, after completing import I do not see the links on any of the tickets.

How do I use a CSV for import and link the new issues to existing issues?

**Note:** https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/How+to+Import+Issue+Links+from+a+CSV+File describes how to link new issues to new issues, but my goal is to link new issues to existing issues on import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this failed originally. This time I simply made a test CSV with two columns (summary, is tested by). is tested by then had an existing issue id in it. Map the is tested by column to a link. 
Import. 
Done.